# How to filter a queryset using a function in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have my models set up like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(defualt = timezone.now())
    .....
    def was_published_in_last_week(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days = 7) <= self.published_date <= now
```

The function checks if an article was published within the last 7 days and it works fine.

However, how do I use this to get a query-set of Articles containing the ones which were published in the last 7 days only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't filter with a function. However, this logic is trivially converted to a filter expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) which works across the model. Functions that you define inside model classes only work on model *instances*.

You are already using the default model manager *`objects`* when you use model classes; you'll just write another one with your custom filter.

```
# First, define a manager subclass
class PublishedLastWeekManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        start = now - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        return super(PublishedLastWeekManager, self).get_queryset().filter(published_date__range=[start, now])

class Article(models.Model):

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published_last_week = PublishedLastWeekManager() # New manager
```

Now, you can do things like:

```
Article.published_last_week.all()
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much. Except PublishedBookManager should be PublishedLastWeekManager.